# Does clustering important for elastic stack?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Could anyone explain to me clearly does clustering is required or not for elastic stack? I know when you set up your elastic in fact you created a single node but I can't understand when I have to set up elasticsearch with multiple nodes? or Does clustering is really important or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch cluster can be created with a single node, but its real power comes when you have multiple nodes in the cluster, that way it can ensure the HA(High availability) and HS(High scalability).

If you running it in Production env. it's highly recommended to use multi-node Elasticsearch cluster, as single node cluster can lead to the data loss(hint: no replica shards will be allocated and Elasticsearch is not a database).

Edit: As discussed in the comments, there are various articles in which its recommended to use the multiple nodes in the Production environment, below is screen-shot from the [official document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/important-settings.html#mdp-migrate).

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but how can I be sure, that I have to implement it, when I looking for metrics which explain what kind of situation should  I begin to implement, I can't find any useful document, I know how much search and writes per second I'll get, how fast my indexes will grow, and what kind of queries my users will run, against what type of content, But I don't know at what kind of situation should I begin?

Comment: @HadiiVarposhti, as mentioned, its always recommended to run multi-node Elasticsearch cluster, you can follow multiple articles over net, and one official I've added in the edit section of my answer.